# problema UnboundLocalError: local variable 'num' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def fnum_aleatorio(a, b, m, semente=None):
    if semente != None:
        num=semente
    num_aleatorio = (num*a+b)%m  
    if num_aleatorio <= a//2:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1
```

estou tentando fazer uma função que apresente um resultado final 0 ou 1, dependendo do numero aleatório que foi criado, mas não consigo terminar por causa desse erro. como proceder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é o escopo da variável `num`.

Ela é declarada dentro do escodo do if:

```
if semente != None:
    num=semente
```

E você ta tentando acessar ela no escopo da função:

`num_aleatorio = (num*a+b)%m`

Vai dar erro porque pro escopo da função `fnum_aleatorio` a variável `num` não existe. Ela só existe dentro do escopo do `if`.

Uma forma de corrigir isso é fazer:

`num = semente if semente is not None else 1`.

Onde `1` é o valor default de `num` quando `semente` for `None`.

Dessa forma você vai estar declarando a variável `num` dentro do escopo da função `fnum_aleatorio`.

Então, ficaria:

```
def fnum_aleatorio(a, b, m, semente=None):
    num = semente if semente is not None else 1
    num_aleatorio = (num*a+b)%m  
    if num_aleatorio <= a//2:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1
```

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda! mas ainda não consegui, parece que ele só me fornece um número, sempre que eu executo o programa, ele dá o mesmo resultado.

Answer (score 0):

Em seu código você só inicia a variável `num` se o `semente` for diferente de `None`, se `semente` for **igual** a `None`  a variavel `num` nunca será iniciada, desta maneira não existe nenhum valor na variável para ser usado no calculo em `num_aleatorio = (num*a+b)%m`, para resolver este problema inicie a variável `num` com `0` (ou qualquer outro valor) do lado de fora do `if` (acima de preferencia), veja:

```
def fnum_aleatorio(a, b, m, semente=None):
    num = 0
    if semente != None:
        num=semente
    num_aleatorio = (num*a+b)%m  
    if num_aleatorio <= a//2:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1
```

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda! mas ainda não consegui, parece que ele só me fornece um número, sempre que eu executo o programa, ele dá o mesmo resultado.